# Best way to play the 101-sum dice game

Tags: probability, dice, algorithmic-game-theory

So i heard about the following game:

Suppose there are two players (or more).
Each player throws a dice in his turn (as many times as he wants), he sums the numbers that comes up - until 1 comes and he gets 0 points for his turn and passes it to the other player. Unless, he chooses to stop before 1 comes and he gets sum-of-the-throws points.

The first player to get to 101 points wins (unless they both gets to it on the same turn and it's a draw)

What is the best way to play this game?

Comment: what if a player has $100$ points and throws a $6$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_(dice_game) Probably reference 4 is what you're after.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention :) First player to get 101 or more wins

Comment: Thanks that's perfect!